# Pasar valor id de un boton a un modal php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, funciones

estoy tratando de pasar un valor desde un boton a un modal de edicion, el desarrollo lo estoy haciendo en php y mysqli las salidas me las esta dando de manera perfecta y la idea es no salir de la misma pag. para hacer modificaciones de los usuarios, pero me he encontrado con que siempre me permite editar el ultimo usuario ingresado y no el seleccionado en el boton editar.

Dejo la function completa:

```
// LISTAR USUARIOS
function lista_usuarios(){
    global $db,  $username, $usua, $mes, $limit_end;
    /* variables */
$order="id DESC";
$url = basename($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]);



if (isset($_GET['pos']))
  $ini=$_GET['pos'];
else
  $ini=1;

$init = ($ini-1) * $limit_end;

/* querys */
$count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";

$user_tipo = 'user';
$query = "  SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE user_type = '$user_tipo'
            ORDER BY id
            DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if (!$row){
//      $_SESSION['success']  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar del usuario ' .$_SESSION['user']['username'] . $mes;

        $mensaje  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar';
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" >';
    echo '<h3>';
    echo $mensaje; 
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';

    } else
    {
        //$mysql = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWD, DB);
        $num = $db->query($count);
        $x = $num->fetch_array();
        $total = ceil($x[0]/$limit_end);

     <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="usuarios.php?id='.$rowid.'">
  Editar
</a>
        echo '<div class="table-responsive">';

        echo '<table id="tabla1" class="table table-bordered table-hover small stacktable">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Id de Usuario</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Condicion</th>
          <th>Accion</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>';

         $c = $db->query($query);
         while($row = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {

          $date = date_create($row['fecha_ingreso']);
          $fecha = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');

          if ($row['status']==1)
          {
            $stdp = 'ACTIVO <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Desactivar</a>';
          } else {
            $stdp = 'BLOQUEADO <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i><a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Activar</a>';

          }

          $rowid = $row['id'];
          $idusuario = $row['idusuario'];
          $nombre_usuario = $row['nombre'];
          $email_usuario = $row['email'];
          $telefono_usuario = $row['tlf'];
          $celular_usuario = $row['cel'];
          $direccion_usuario = $row['direccion'];
          $ciudad_usuario = $row['ciudad'];
          $estado_usuario = $row['estado'];
          $municipio_usuario = $row['municipio'];
          $parroquia_usuario = $row['parroquia'];
          //$password_usuario = $row['password'];
          $status_usuario = $row['status'];

          $acciones_usuario = '
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="usuarios.php?id='.$rowid.'">
  Editar
</a>

<!-- Modal Boton Editar -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Usuario</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">';

      $acciones_usuario .= ' <form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "usuarios.php">';

      $acciones_usuario .= 'Identificador: ' .$rowid;

      $acciones_usuario .= '<div class="form-group">
      <label for="idusuario">Id del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idusuario" aria-describedby="idusuario" placeholder="Ingrese el idusuario" name="idusuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $idusuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el numero de ID del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre_usuario">Nombre del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_usuario" aria-describedby="nombre_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Nombre del Usuario" name="nombre_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $nombre_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el numero de ID del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email_usuario">Email del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_usuario" aria-describedby="email_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Email del Usuario" name="email_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $email_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Email del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="telefono_usuario">Telefono del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono_usuario" aria-describedby="telefono_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Telefono del Usuario" name="telefono_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $telefono_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Telefono del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="celular_usuario">Celular del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celular_usuario" aria-describedby="celular_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Celular del Usuario" name="celular_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $celular_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Celular del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="direccion_usuario">Direccion del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion_usuario" aria-describedby="direccion_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese la Direccion" name="direccion_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $direccion_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Direccion del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ciudad_usuario">Ciudad del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad_usuario" aria-describedby="ciudad_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese la Ciudad" name="ciudad_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $ciudad_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar la Ciudad del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estado_usuario">Estado del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado_usuario" aria-describedby="estado_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Estado" name="estado_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $estado_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Estado de ubicacion del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estado_usuario">Status del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status_usuario" aria-describedby="status_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Status" name="status_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $status_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>

      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Status del Usuario 1 Para activarlo y 0 para Desactivarlo.</div>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="editar_usuario_btn">Enviar</button>

      </form>';


      $acciones_usuario .= '</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';

 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['idusuario'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['nombre'] .'</td>
       <td>'.$row['email'] .'</td>
       <td>'.$stdp .'</td>
       <td>'.$acciones_usuario .'</td>';
         } 
          echo '</tr></tbody></table>';

           /* numeración de registros*/
// echo "<div class='pagination'>";
echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">';
echo '<ul class="pagination">';
/****************************************/
if(($ini - 1) == 0)
{
  echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#'>&laquo;</a></li>";
}
else
{
  echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?pos=".($ini-1)."'><b>&laquo;</b></a></li>";
}
/****************************************/
for($k=1; $k <= $total; $k++)
{
  if($ini == $k)
  {
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#'><b>".$k."</b></a></li>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?pos=$k'>".$k."</a></li>";
  }
}
/****************************************/
if($ini == $total)
{
  echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#'>&raquo;</a></li>";
}
else
{
  echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?pos=".($ini+1)."'><b>&raquo;</b></a></li>";
}
/*******************END*******************/
echo "</ul>";
// echo "</div>";
echo '</nav>';
}


}
```

Esta funcion muestra una lista de datos que recupera de la table users, recuperando los siguientes datos ID Id de Usuario   Nombre  Email   Condicion   Accion, en esta ultima columna accion se muestra un boton editar

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="usuarios.php?id='.$rowid.'">
  Editar
</a>
```

Al pasar el mouse muestra el id del respectivo usuario que se desea modificar al dar click se da acceso a un modal que contiene:

```
<div class="modal-body">';

      $acciones_usuario .= ' <form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "usuarios.php">';

      $acciones_usuario .= 'Identificador: ' .$rowid;

      $acciones_usuario .= '<div class="form-group">
      <label for="idusuario">Id del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idusuario" aria-describedby="idusuario" placeholder="Ingrese el idusuario" name="idusuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $idusuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el numero de ID del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre_usuario">Nombre del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_usuario" aria-describedby="nombre_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Nombre del Usuario" name="nombre_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $nombre_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el numero de ID del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email_usuario">Email del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_usuario" aria-describedby="email_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Email del Usuario" name="email_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $email_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Email del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="telefono_usuario">Telefono del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono_usuario" aria-describedby="telefono_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Telefono del Usuario" name="telefono_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $telefono_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Telefono del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="celular_usuario">Celular del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celular_usuario" aria-describedby="celular_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Celular del Usuario" name="celular_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $celular_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Celular del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="direccion_usuario">Direccion del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion_usuario" aria-describedby="direccion_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese la Direccion" name="direccion_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $direccion_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Direccion del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ciudad_usuario">Ciudad del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad_usuario" aria-describedby="ciudad_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese la Ciudad" name="ciudad_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $ciudad_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar la Ciudad del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estado_usuario">Estado del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado_usuario" aria-describedby="estado_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Estado" name="estado_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $estado_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Estado de ubicacion del Usuario.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estado_usuario">Status del Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status_usuario" aria-describedby="status_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el Status" name="status_usuario" value="';
      $acciones_usuario .= $status_usuario;
      $acciones_usuario .= '" required>

      <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Status del Usuario 1 Para activarlo y 0 para Desactivarlo.</div>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="editar_usuario_btn">Enviar</button>

      </form>'
```

Pero asi se le de click al boton editar del usuario 1 o usuario 2 siempre recuperara los datos de edicion del ultimo usuario agregado a la base de datos.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, ¿qué significa?: *pero me he encontrado con que siempre me permite editar el ultimo usuario ingresado y no el seleccionado en el boton editar*. ¿Dónde ocurre lo que dices en el código que compartes?

Comment: Gracias por escribir @A.Cedano he editado mi consulta, principalmente se recuperan datos de la base de datos usuarios y son mostrados en una tabla, eso ocurre sin problemas, e incluso tambien el boton editar de cada usuario es mostrado sin conflicto, al pasar el mouse muestra el link al valor get, pero al dar click no pasa los datos del valor get a los datos del formulario de edicion correspondiente al usuario seleccionado.